# Swift Login app

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a new login app by Xcode. I had been written my code but something goes wrong with it.

The code looks like to be correct but when debugging its skip from "Task" to the end of code , any help ?
Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) { //login button

    let UserName = input.text!
    let UserPassword = password.text!

    if ( UserName.isEmpty || UserPassword.isEmpty) { return }

    //send data user to server side 
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://servertest.cf/Store.php?LoginUser=Test%40home.com&LoginPassword=123456789")
    let myRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)

    myRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "email=\(UserName)&Password=\(UserPassword)";

    myRequest.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let Task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(myRequest)
        { data , response , error in

            if error != nil {
                println("error\(error)")

                self.myLabel.text = "wrong user name"
            }

            var err : NSError?
            var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers , error: &err) as? NSDictionary

           if let parseJson = json
           {
            var resultValue:String = parseJson["Status"] as! String!

            println("result\(resultValue)")

            if(resultValue == "Success" )
            {
                var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                var vc: UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! UINavigationController

                self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    Task.resume()
}
```

Comment: It doesn't skip, it performs the task asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

The closure is queued to another queue and run in another thread. Add a breakpoint inside the closure if you want to run it line-by-line.